# Referencing jquery object in method paramater

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to somehow reference the current jquery object/collection in a method parameter...

For example

```
$('#sub > :last-child').height($('#sub > :last-child').height() + (gap * -1));
```

Can I somehow change the second reference, or am I stuck with storing in a variable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a function you can get the current value.

```
$('#sub > :last-child').height(function(i, value) {
    return value + (gap * -1);
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UetA/)